# Test class will not find instance variable getter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby! When I run my test script it throws an exception:

NoMethodError: undefined method `num=' for #
Did you mean?  num

Why isn't able to find it? Thank you!

Here is my class

```
class FizzBuzz
 def initialize(num = 0)
   @num = num
   @fb = 'FizzBuzz'
   post_init
end


 def post_init
  nil
 end

 def num
  @num
 end
 def fb
  @fb
 end

def num(value = 0)
@num = value
end

def fb(value = 0)
   @fb = value
 end

end
```

Here is an example of the test case

```
 def setup
      @obj = FizzBuzz.new()
 end

 #Test multiple of 3 results in instance attribute fb being set to Fizz
 def test_fb_three
     @obj.num = 42
     assert_equal  "Fizz", @obj.fb, "Incorrect value for fb.\nExpected\"Fizz\" got \"#{@obj.fb}\""
   end
```

Here is the stack trace:

NoMethodError: undefined method `num=' for #<FizzBuzz:0x33b46a8 @num=0, @fb="FizzBuzz">
Did you mean?  num
C:/Users/frase/RubymineProjects/HW/test_hw4.rb:54:in`test_fb_three'
    (eval):12:in `run'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/RubyMine 2017.1/rb/testing/patch/testunit/test/unit/ui/teamcity/testrunner.rb:93:in`start_mediator'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/RubyMine 2017.1/rb/testing/patch/testunit/test/unit/ui/teamcity/testrunner.rb:81:in `start'

edit: adding test case example, and cleaning

Comment: Change `def num(value = 0)` to `def num=(value = 0)` ?

Comment: That gives me a syntax error, which says that it's expecting a expression

Comment: Hey Steven. How are you calling the `initialize` method? Can you post the exact error? Please read "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. At the moment there's no way for anyone to verify your problem and help you come to a solution.

Comment: @JamesMilani I have cleaned it up, added the stacktrace, and the test method. Is this enough info for you to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why isn't able to find it?

Because you didn't write it. You wrote *two* method definitions for a method named `num`. Since you cannot have two methods with the same name, the second definition will simply overwrite the first one.

Please, look at the error message: it is telling you that it is looking for a method named `num=`. There is no such method in your code.

Presumably, you meant the second `num` method to be named `num=`. You need to rename it:

```
def num=(value = 0)
  @num = value
end
```

Note that the optional parameter with default value is useless here: you can't call a writer method without arguments anyway, you must always supply exactly one argument. (Ignoring reflection.)

Comment: You're right! I guess from my experience with other languages I assumed it would overload it, rather than overwrite it.

Comment: Well, even if it *did* overload it still wouldn't work, since the name of the method you are calling is `num=` and the name of the method you are defining is `num`. I don't know of any language where that would work.